# Using same check point location for more than one consumers - Spark direct streaming

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

Is it OK to use same check point location for more than one consumers? We are using Direct Streaming approach.

**Code Sample:**

```
ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)
val dstream1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet1).map(_._2)
val dstream2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet2).map(_._2)
```

Is there going to be any problem, if i use same check point location for more than one consumers? the reason we have two different consumers is, both are different data and different topic.

In the check point location, is it going to create separate directory for each topic offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the check point location, is it going to create separate directory
>   for each topic offset?

That would be problematic. When you create a directory for checkpointing, data is saved in the following format:

```
new Path(checkpointDir, PREFIX + checkpointTime.milliseconds)
```

Where the `PREFIX` is `checkpoint-`. You're going to see something like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark spark 9434 Feb 14 17:59 checkpoint-1487095188000
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark spark 9456 Feb 14 17:59 checkpoint-1487095188000.bk
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark spark 9423 Feb 14 17:59 checkpoint-1487095192000
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark spark 9443 Feb 14 17:59 checkpoint-1487095192000.bk
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark spark 9426 Feb 14 17:59 checkpoint-1487095196000
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark spark 9446 Feb 14 17:59 checkpoint-1487095196000.bk
```

Where you can see my batch interval is 4000 milliseconds.

Since your streams operate on a common `StreamingContext`, they are both using the same batch interval and are going to attempt to override each others files. Worse, you could mistakenly try to recover one streams data inside the other.

Use separate checkpoint directories for each stream.

> What if i have single consumer with multiple topics?

If you have a single consumer, than that same `StreamingContext` is in charge of checkpointing everything related to *all topics*, and that is safe, there should be no problem doing that.

Comment: Thanks, what if i have single consumer with multiple topics? Because we have another job where we have one consumer with multiple topics and check point is enabled, could you please update your asnwer for this as well?

Comment: @Shankar Updated.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer, i learned many things related to spark streaming from your answer...